# django - choice from ForeignKey - adding new values when creating antoher model

Tags: django, field

i am making app in which one module stores addresses. I figured out, that for preventing typos I would like to have cities/countries linked via ForeignKey to my Customer_address model. The con of that way is that i have to populate my Cities_Countries model. Is it possible with Django to, while adding new customer address, have choice field like which can show value (like ForeignKey ) or accept brand new one and save to the Cities_Countries model ?

Comment: what have you tried? this works fine in the django admin using foreignkeys models. in a custom form you can use inline forms to add a new linked field, or jquery/ajax if you prefer.

Comment: actually I have not tryide anything yet as I don't have clue how to do this. What did you mean by "works fine in django admin" ? I tried, and only have already written entries. For now jquery/ajax is a black matter for me and I want to learn that later, so now I use only django and html.

Comment: i suggest you go through the entire tutorial then... it will show you how ForeignKey's work in the admin